# Category foreach Paging

Tags: categories, pagination, php, previous, next

I'm using the following code to display categories on my homepage, what I'd like to do is add the ability for paging with previous and next links, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this with a `foreach` can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Original Code:**

```
<?php 
    $cat = get_cat_ID("Photos");
    $categories = get_categories("child_of=$cat");
?>
<?php if (is_array($categories) && count($categories) > 0) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <?php query_posts("cat=$category->cat_ID&orderby=rand&posts_per_page=1"); ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>?cat=<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail("gallery-thumb"); ?></a>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php query_posts("cat=$category->cat_ID&orderby=name&posts_per_page=1"); ?>
    <h3><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>?cat=<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>"><?php single_cat_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php $query = $category->count; ?>
    <?php if ($query == 1) $query .= " Image"; else $query .=" Images"; echo '<p class="center">('.$query.')</p>'; //Album Count ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <p>I hate to break it to you...but right now there are <strong>no albums available</strong> for viewing, please try again later.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Code Update:**

```
<?php
    $parent = get_cat_ID("Photos");
    $cats = get_categories("child_of=$parent");
?>
<?php foreach ($cats as $cat) { ?>
    <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
    <?php $query = $cat->count; ?>
    <?php if ($query == 1) $query .= " Image"; else $query .=" Images"; echo '<p class="center">('.$query.')</p>'; //Album Count ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: WP pagination isn't going help in this way. You could just make your own using jQuery and `count($categories)` to get the total number of sub-categories and then work that into your `foreach` loop to (for example): display the first 6 subs and hide the rest; and, add pagination accordingly to hide the first 6, show next 6, etc.. make sense? Just an option.

Comment: Running multiple queries, and specially using `query_posts` is not going to help your cause here. I'm not going to say it is not doable with the proper functions and properplanning, but you are going to have a tough time getting this to work

Comment: I have reworked the code and the updated code (shown above) is a lot easier to read and pretty much does the same thing (it's just missing the post image, but that's ok). How would I paginate that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!

After a lot of research and trial and error, I managed to figure out how to get the paging to work for both versions...my original code and the simplified code update.

**Original Code Solution:**

```
<?php
    $cat = get_cat_ID("Photos");
    $categories = get_categories("child_of=$cat");

    $limit = 9;

    $total = count($categories);
    $pages = ceil($total / $limit);
    $result = ceil($total / $limit);

    $current = isset($_GET['paged']) ? $_GET['paged'] : 1;
    $next = $current < $pages ? $current + 1 : null;
    $previous = $current > 1 ? $current - 1 : null;

    $offset = ($current - 1) * $limit;
    $categories = array_slice($categories, $offset, $limit);
?>

<?php if (is_array($categories) && count($categories) > 0) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <?php query_posts("cat=$category->cat_ID&orderby=rand&posts_per_page=1"); ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>?cat=<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail("gallery-thumb"); ?></a>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <?php query_posts("cat=$category->cat_ID&orderby=name&posts_per_page=1"); ?>
            <h3><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>?cat=<?php echo $category->cat_ID; ?>"><?php single_cat_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <?php $query = $category->count; ?>
        <?php if ($query == 1) $query .= " Image"; else $query .=" Images"; echo '<p class="center">('.$query.')</p>'; //Album Count ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <p>I hate to break it to you...but right now there are <strong>no albums available</strong> for viewing, please try again later.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php echo "<p>(Page: ". $current . " of " . $result .")</p>"; ?>
        <? if($previous): ?>
            <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>?paged=<?= $previous ?>">Previous</a>
        <? endif ?>
        <? if($next) : ?>
            <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>?paged=<?= $next ?>">Next</a>
        <? endif ?>
```

**Code Update Solution:**

```
<?php
    $parent = get_cat_ID("Photos");
    $cats = get_categories("child_of=$parent");

    $limit = 9;

    $total = count($cats);
    $pages = ceil($total / $limit);
    $result = ceil($total / $limit);

    $current = isset($_GET['paged']) ? $_GET['paged'] : 1;
    $next = $current < $pages ? $current + 1 : null;
    $previous = $current > 1 ? $current - 1 : null;

    $offset = ($current - 1) * $limit;
    $cats = array_slice($cats, $offset, $limit);
?>

<?php foreach ($cats as $cat) { ?>
    <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
    <?php $query = $cat->count; ?>
    <?php if ($query == 1) $query .= " Image"; else $query .=" Images"; echo '<p class="center">('.$query.')</p>'; //Album Count ?>
<?php } ?>

<?php echo "<p>(Page: ". $current . " of " . $result .")</p>"; ?>
<? if($previous): ?>
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>?paged=<?= $previous ?>">Previous</a>
<? endif ?>
<? if($next) : ?>
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>?paged=<?= $next ?>">Next</a>
<? endif ?>
```

The middle sections is where my original code is on both solutions, the top and bottom parts are where most of the changes have been made.

I found the solution here: http://erikeldridge.wordpress.com/2009/01/11/simple-php-paging/ - I just changed the array that he had and added the category array that I have, then configured the paging url and added a "(Page # of #)" to finish it up.

Everything works like a champ!

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score -2):

Here's some pagination I used for a foreach loop:

```
function foreach_pagination( $current, $pages, $link = '?page=%d', $tag = 'ul', $item_tag = 'li' )
{
  $min = ( $current - 3 < $pages && $current - 3 > 0 ) ? $current - 3 : 1;
  $max = ( $current + 3 > $pages ) ? $pages : $current + 3;

  $output = array();

  for( $i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++ )
  {
    if($current == $i)
      $output[] = "<span class='active'>{$i}</span>";
    else
      $output[] = '<a href="'.sprintf($link,$i).'">' . $i . '</a>';
  }

  if ( $current + 1 < $pages )
    $output[] = '<a href="' . sprintf( $link, $current + 1 ) . '">Next</a>';

  if ( $current - 1 > 0 )
     array_unshift($output, '<a href="'.sprintf($link,$current-1).'">Previous</a>');


  $li = '';
  foreach( $output as $link ):  
      $li .= sprintf( '<%s>%s</%s>', $item_tag, $link, $item_tag );
  endforeach;

  return sprintf( '<%s>%s</%s>', $tag, $li, $tag );

}
```

Comment: This looks great, I add this to my functions file right? How do I use it in my template?

Comment: You would add that function to your functions file and then call it after your loop in your template. I haven't used the piece of code in a really long time, but as I remember I took it from: 
http://zurb.com/forrst/posts/PHP_Simple_pagination_function-vHK

Hopefully this helps you more!

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out how to implement your solution, but I solved my problem. Looks like your solution is pretty similar...just wrapped up in a function instead of being added on the page. Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: @user3325126 whay you don't paste the code here? Answer should not rely on external links.

Comment: @G.M. Sorry I'm newer to stackexchange and was having trouble making the code readable. Sorry I'm working on it!

Comment: @user3325126 Welcome here. [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help) you can find some help.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?